# Python web crawling and Telegram bot. Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm currently building a Telegram bot that provides information about school lunches.
However, an error occurs in get.Updates(): in my code.

```
import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
# print(now)

day = now[:4] + now[5:7] + now[8:10]
# print(day)

req = requests.get("https://school.cbe.go.kr/cbt-h/M010304/list?ymd=" + now)
# print(req.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
# print(soup)

ag = soup.find("a", href="/cbt-h/M010304/list?ymd=" + day)
# print(ag)

litg = ag.find_all('li')
# print(litg)

diet = ""
for i in litg:
    diet = diet + i.text + "\n"
# print(diet)

## 2. bot code

import telegram

token = "token"
Bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)

for i in Bot.get_updates():
    print(i.message)
```

This is my code and the error message is Traceback (most recent call last):

**RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.get_updates' was never awaited
for i in Bot.get_updates():
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/myname/Desktop/Coding/school/main.py", line 34, in 
for i in Bot.get_updates():
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable**

It pops up like this.

I would like to know what is wrong, can you write some code to fix it and send me it?

I also tried using python async by getting the chat ID through a token.
I searched YouTube and searched the web, but I couldn't find any code that helped me.

Comment: Might this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400778/typeerror-coroutine-object-is-not-iterable